# Cannot use dpkg - "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)" on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, dpkg

I have a similar problem to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224651/cannot-use-apt-get-dpkg-input-output-error/224670#224670).

While running `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I had this error:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libgs9-common': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by following the steps shown [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1232143.html).

1. `cd /var/lib/dpkg`
2. `cp status ~/status.copy`
3. Edit the `status` file by removing the lines corresponding to the problematic package (in my case "libgs9-common"). Just remove the lines from this package, not the lines from other packages having this package as a dependency.
4. Save the `status` file
5. `sudo dpkg --configure-a`
6. `sudo apt-get -f install`

Now, `dpkg` will work normally. So, you can run: `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Manipulating the status file like this is really bad. You just sweep the error under the carpet by making `dpkg` think that package is not installed. I am pretty sure this will bite you at some point. Input/Output errors normally mean - like the linked question suggests - file system corruption or disk hardware problems. Did you try running a file system check first to find and fix these problems? Also check your disk health (SMART status).